# Passing data type argument for feature selection in mlr package

Tags: r, feature-selection, mlr

I have just started to experiment with `mlr` package and I love the ease of training models and all other things that it can do.

However, I am stuck at the `feature selection` section which is the last part of this code. What I intend to do is apply `variance` method to `generateFilterValuesData()` and I know variance can only be applied to numeric values and thus I am trying to explore if there is an `inbuilt parameter` that can allow the data to subsetted by data type and the function can then be applied to the task below.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(mlr)

data(BreastCancer, package = "mlbench")
df = BreastCancer

df$Id = NULL #unimportant feature
names(df) <- tolower(names(df))

cols = c(1:5)
df[,cols] = sapply(cols, function(x){df[,x] = as.integer(df[,x])})
glimpse(df)


classif.task= makeClassifTask(id = 'BreastCancer',data = df,
                              target = 'class')
#task is created
classif.task


#imputation
imp = impute(classif.task,cols = list(bare.nuclei = imputeMode()))

#feature importance
feature.imp = generateFilterValuesData(task = imp$task,
                          method = c('variance'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `subsetTask`, e.g.

```
subsetTask(iris.task, sapply(getTaskData(iris.task), is.numeric))
```